# How would I create conditional fields on install?

Tags: entities, installation

I am creating a content type in a module so that it gets created on install.

I got the fields and field instances in separate files and include those files in the .install file. I then call **field_create_field()** and **field_create_instance()** in the install file.

However, I also have [conditional_fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) for this content type. I have the code to create the conditions, what I need to know is what function do I now call from the .install file like I did with the other two field functions?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting this to work by creating a feature for the node and copying the array to the module.

To get the 'ID' of the **dependee** and **dependent**, I used *field_info_instance*. After I had that I could pass that info to *conditional_fields_dependency_insert*.

I did all this in *hook_install*.